# Report Wizard in an MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, reporting

After some research, I understand that we can use sql server reporting in an mvc application as long as the view engine is web form instead of razor.

The tutorial I have been trying to follow is:

[Creating an ASP.net reporting using Visual Studio 2010](http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/09/creating-an-asp-net-report-using-visual-studio-2010-part-1.aspx)

The problem is in Part 2. I cannot find the local classes listed as Data Source. The only choice is to set up a new xsd file to connect to the database. How can I have my reports to use my data repositories as their data source?

Comment: Did you verify that 'The “Data Source” may show up empty. To get it populated, make sure your project is compiled and there is an index.aspx file in the root folder. This may be a bug.'?

Comment: Oh! Do I have to have an index.aspx file in the root folder?

Comment: You are definitely right. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: You shouldn't in MVC, but that is the only thing I could find in the post you made.  http://jarrettmeyer.com/post/1462680178/simple-report-generation-in-asp-net-mvc looks promising, but uses Crystal.

Answer (score 2):

The credit goes to TNCodeMonkey!

Not only the project has to be compiled first, we must have an index.aspx file in the root folder of the MVC Web Application.

I don't know why. But the Data source is populated with all my dll's once that magic file is in place.